# WSIG Deployment BUILD FAILED

Tags: web-services, ant, pug

I would like to use wsig : I followed the guide .
So in step of deployement:

1. Prepare the WSIG web application content in the webModule directory. This step can be performed by means of the build target of the ANT build file included in the WSIG distribution.

   When I launch the command ANT like this :

c:\JADE-all-4.5.0\add-ons\wsig>ant build.xml

it's displays this error :
buildfile: C:\Users\acer\Downloads\JADE-all-4.5.0\add-ons\wsig\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "build.xml" does not exist in the project "wsig".

I checked the folder wsig ,  build.xml  file exists in wsig folder.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
>ant -f build.xml
```

If you need to specify a target in the build.xml file then put that on the end. For example -

```
ant -f build.xml mytarget
```

See [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi, it's ok now tank you

Comment: Cool. Could you mark this as the answer if my answer helped you? Thanks.